# com object instance cannot be reconverted to com object

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

I am trying to automate Microstation using python and win32com but I get the following error trying to resend an object created through the COM interface. Can anyone help me troubleshoot?

```
import win32com.client

MS = win32com.client.Dispatch("MicroStationDGN.Application")
MS.Visible = 1

DF = MS.OpenDesignFile("C:\\mydgn.dgn", False)
print(DF.Models.Count)

startPoint = MS.Point3dFromXYZ(2.0,2.0,0.0)
endPoint = MS.Point3dFromXYZ(4.0,4.0,0.0)

line = MS.CreateLineElement2(None, startPoint, endPoint)
print(line)
MS.ActiveModelReference.AddElement(line)
line.redraw()
```

on the `AddElement` line i get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-54f93cd6e4bc> in <module>()
     16 line = MS.CreateLineElement2(None, startPoint, endPoint)
     17 print(line)
---> 18 MS.ActiveModelReference.AddElement(line)
     19 line.redraw()
     20 

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.6\CF9F97BF-39F2-4B8E-835C-8BE9E99DAF5Bx0x8x0.py in AddElement(self, Element)
  16408 
  16409         def AddElement(self, Element=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
> 16410         return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1610743813, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((9, 1),),Element
  16411             )
  16412 

TypeError: The Python instance can not be converted to a COM object
```

but the print gives me a valid com object...

```
(<win32com.gen_py.Bentley MicroStation DGN 8.9 Object
Library._LineElement instance at 0x119452224>, com_struct(X=2.0,
Y=2.0, Z=0.0), com_struct(X=4.0, Y=4.0, Z=0.0))
```

The equivalent in ExcelVBA would be the following assuming Microstation DGN Library is loaded as a reference module.

```vb
Sub MSFromXlReference()

Dim MS As MicroStationDGN.Application
Dim DesignFile As DesignFile
Dim Line As LineElement
Dim startPoint As Point3d
Dim endPoint As Point3d

Set MS = New MicroStationDGN.Application
MS.Visible = 1

Set DesignFile = 
MS.OpenDesignFile("C:\\mydgn.dgn", False)

startPoint = MS.Point3dFromXYZ(2#, 2#, 0#)
endPoint = MS.Point3dFromXYZ(4#, 4#, 0#)

Set Line = MS.CreateLineElement2(Nothing, startPoint, endPoint)

MS.ActiveModelReference.AddElement Line
Line.redraw

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a VBA version of this code available?

Comment: added VBA code at the end of the post